# Creating Subdomains Programmatically

Tags: .net, php, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, subdomain

I am looking for a solution to create subdomains programmatically in ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC and PHP. Specifically, a user profile page should resolve for both: `www.domain.com/profilename` or `http://profilename.domain.com` .

Comment: This question is really unanswerable.  You'd be better off tackling one part of it at a time.  DNS setup, .NET code, PHP code, etc...

Comment: yes you are right and I am not actually looking for a solution but wondering how it is being done...

Though I was expecting some codes written for HttpModuleHandlers and also new Routing properties in asp.net 4..

But I think more interesting answers will be posted here :)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Update your DNS settings of the particular domain so that *.domain.com all point to the same host.

Then, programmatically check and see if the first part of the URL used contains the subdomain you are looking for, and act accordingly.  For example, if the first part contains a given profilename, then retrieve that particular profiles collection of data from your DB and display it to the user.

Make sure your web application uses relative links, so that if the user arrives at the site using a subdomain, that you don't redirect them elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

There is no generic way to create subdomains. You will need to call an API provided by your ISP or DNS provider -- typically SOAP or REST.

Either that, or use a wildcard domain (*).

On the IIS side, be sure to configure you application so that it doesn't use Host headers.

Comment: Every site that does something like this uses wildcard domains.  Actually creating individual DNS entries would mean long DNS propagation delays, insanely bloated zone files, etc.

Comment: It depends on how many subdomains you need (the OP didn't specify).  Wildcarding is not always the best way to go, particularly if you're concerned about scalability.  Here's a link to an example API for creating new subdomains, provided by a managed DNS service: https://durabledns.com/help/downloads/DurableDNS%20SOAP%20API%20Documentation%20v3.0.pdf

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
AppDomain subDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("ProfileUserDomain");
```

Although you may have to configure your DNS to allow request from your code. Dynamic DNS services could be your answer.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Do you have any info about configuring Dynamic DNS services on IIS ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to add dynamic dns software onto your webserver or windows server, but hopefully using an account off a dedicated server will help you out: http://howto.wired.com/wiki/Set_Up_Dynamic_DNS