# I would like to create subdomains Dynamically under my domain using asp.net ,C#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net

I would like to create subdomains Dynamically under my domain using asp.net ,C#?
I can not find good solution for this.
What are the things i should do to complete this.

Scenario:
1.user register with site
2.domain name should be: http://username.domain.com

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943356/creating-subdomains-programmatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most DNS providers allow you to specify [wildcard DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record). That means you have an entry something like "*.example.com" that maps to your IP address.

If you do this, then you do not have to modify DNS entries on the fly, you just need to add an internal mapping in your database (or whatever) saying that "user1.example.com maps to user1", etc.